# Failed to generate captcha image, content has already been output

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, captcha

i m using [secureimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/) solution to generate captcha code

i have this error on chrom console

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

and when entring on this url directly used as image src

> securimage_show.php?sid=fa5e1eb19c3a534885632e

i have this error

> Failed to generate captcha image, content has already been output.
>   This is most likely due to misconfiguration or a PHP error was sent to
>   the browse

someone have idea ?

Note: it works for me in localhost wampserver but not on remote server

Edit:

the code from the captcha opensource code generating php errors :

```
 protected function output()
{
    if ($this->canSendHeaders() || $this->send_headers == false) {
        if ($this->send_headers) {
            // only send the content-type headers if no headers have been output
            // this will ease debugging on misconfigured servers where warnings
            // may have been output which break the image and prevent easily viewing
            // source to see the error.
            header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
            header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . "GMT");
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
        }

        switch ($this->image_type) {
            case self::SI_IMAGE_JPEG:
                if ($this->send_headers) header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($this->im, null, 90);
                break;
            case self::SI_IMAGE_GIF:
                if ($this->send_headers) header("Content-Type: image/gif");
                imagegif($this->im);
                break;
            default:
                if ($this->send_headers) header("Content-Type: image/png");
                imagepng($this->im);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<hr /><strong>'
            .'Failed to generate captcha image, content has already been '
            .'output.<br />This is most likely due to misconfiguration or '
            .'a PHP error was sent to the browser.</strong>';
    }

    imagedestroy($this->im);
    restore_error_handler();

    if (!$this->no_exit) exit;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some of your code?

Comment: i will see but it works for me in localhost but not on remote server

Comment: You forgot to include the crucial `if` statement that evaluates to false...

Comment: @jeroen: edited (add entire function)

Comment: @khaled_webdev Hi Khaled, are you still having this problem?  If so I can provide you a solution.  I am the author of Securimage captcha.

Comment: @drew010 : thanks nice to meet you and good work, yes i have hide it for this project, i have use it before for other website in other server and it's working, i think it's a server config problem (sorry for my english)

Comment: @khaled_webdev See if this updated copy of [securimage.php](https://raw.github.com/dapphp/securimage/master/securimage.php) resolves the issue for you.  It is probably a configuration error in php.ini that is causing an error to be generated (but not displayed) and securimage is incorrectly showing you the error about content already being output.

Comment: @drew010 : many thanks , i will see it and test it when i have time to come back to this website

Comment: @khaled_webdev You're welcome, feel free to contact me directly via the email address in securimage.php as well if you need further help.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Quick Fix:

Just replace canSendHeaders function in securimage.php file

From

```
protected function canSendHeaders() {

    if (headers_sent()) {

        // output has been flushed and headers have already been sent
        return false;
    } else if (strlen((string) ob_get_contents()) > 0) {
        // headers haven't been sent, but there is data in the buffer that will break image and audio data
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To

```
protected function canSendHeaders() {

    ob_get_clean();

    if (headers_sent()) {

        // output has been flushed and headers have already been sent
        return false;
    } else if (strlen((string) ob_get_contents()) > 0) {
        // headers haven't been sent, but there is data in the buffer that will break image and audio data
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to generate captcha image, content has already been output. This is most likely due to misconfiguration or a PHP error was sent to the browse

I think you are missing reference to the dll in your web.config

Comment: unfortunately it's a shared server and can't config

Comment: web.config? His question is regarding PHP, it sounds like you're referring to a .NET web app...

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this statement that evaluates to `false`:

```
if ($this->canSendHeaders() || $this->send_headers == false) {
```

you have already sent stuff to the browser before you call the `output` function.

In order to be able to use that function, you must make sure that nothing has been sent to the browser; no empty lines or spaces before opening `<?php` tags, no `echo` statements, etc.

Comment: @khaled_webdev Could be something as simple as a space or a new-line that gets ignored by wamp but not by the server.

Comment: I have changed this condition if ($this->canSendHeaders() || $this->send_headers == false) to if(1==1) to ignore it. Are there any side effect for this?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem this morning with a development that i've done some month ago, while deploying today i've forgotten that i place an echo on the top of securimage.php, hope this can help

Comment: thanks for you, i have just remove the condition of error message and works like a charm without any problem, maybe is not the best solution but it works for me. Yes i have to verifiy any echo or empty lines like recommend jeron, the author.